# How do I get the expression of $d \overline {\Pi} ([a,b])$?

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, poisson-geometry

[image]

Could anyone please shade some light on the on the penultimate argument made by the author i.e. "The difference (i)-(ii) vanishes up to second order as $t \to 0,$ and $t^2$ term reads..."

The equation on the bottom of this argument is something involving differential but the author indicates something which seems irrelevant to me.